# Updating identify tool every time feature is selected with PyQGIS3

Tags: qgis, update, pyqgis-3

I want to use the "Identify Feature Tool" in code (PyQGIS3). What I've found in the internet doesn't use the tool, people usually print in console point features and ids. I also found a tool that would open a window form with the point information but this method won't get attached to the docks or update itself.

I am providing examples of the methods I found below:

METHOD 1 (Printing features on console):

```
atriVector = self.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
featget = atriVector.getFeatures()

atributes = [i.attributes() for i in featget]

print("{}".format(atributes[0][0]))
```

METHOD 2 (opening a feature form):

```
atriVector = self.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
f = atriVector.selectedFeatures()[0]
self.iface.openFeatureForm(atriVector, f)
```

This method as I said before won't update itself, it would open a new window for every selected feature.

These two methods are the ones closer to what I am expecting (which is the actual tool from QGIS interface)

Here is an screenshot of it:

I want to use this tool with PyQGIS, but I have only found previous methods which are not close to what I expect.

[image: Identify Feature Tool]

See that in the image there is a selected feature and in the box the information of the feature is shown.