# What is the equivalent of QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature in PyQGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis-3

I was trying to use the  QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature() tool as shown in an answer of StackOverflow, but when executed it gave the error:

```
'QgisInterface' object has no attribute 'QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature'
```

I am assuming it was deprecated, in that case how do I call this tool in PyQgis3.4?

Comment: Have you seen this thread [IdentifyFeature() use via PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130552/identifyfeature-use-via-pyqgis)?

Comment: How are you using `QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature()`?

Comment: @Joseph I am using it as `self.iface.QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(atriVector, f)` where atriVector=vectorLayer and f=selectedFeature

Comment: @Taras   I saw the post, I understand that `QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature` is a signal, is it right? I am looking for a way to open the IdentifyFeature tool using the selected feature, but I haven't found the actual tool yet, there are these methods: `self.iface.actionIdentify().trigger()` , `self.iface.openFeatureForm(atriVector, f)` , `self.iface.showAttributeTable(atriVector)` but non of them opens the actual tool used in the qgis interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature** is not deprecated in QGIS 3

https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapToolIdentifyFeature.html

`self.iface.QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(atriVector, f)` is not correct way,you need create a instance for `QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature` and set map tool after.

I add a minimal example

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor

def onFeatureIdentified(feature):
    fid = feature.id()
    print ("feature selected : " + str(fid))

layer = iface.activeLayer()
mc=iface.mapCanvas()
mapTool = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(mc)
mapTool.setLayer(layer)
mc.setMapTool(mapTool)
mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(onFeatureIdentified)
```

Comment: This answers the post question, now @Fran Raga  do you have any idea about using the Identify tool that shows selected feature's information table available in the Qgis gui in PyQgis?

Comment: Post a new question please, @Thriskel

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316003/updating-identify-tool-every-time-feature-is-selected-with-pyqgis the question is already open