# Call a QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature mapTool with a button in a QGIS3 plugin

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

In QGIS 3.12, I'm trying to get a feature on the mapCanvas from a plugin trough a pushButton. I used the code from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316110/what-is-the-equivalent-of-qgsmaptoolidentifyfeature-in-pyqgis-3) but it doesn't work in the plugin although it works fine in the QGIS python Editor.

```py
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature

def onFeatureIdentified(feature):
    fid = feature.id()
    print ("feature selected : " + str(fid))

layer = iface.activeLayer()
mc=iface.mapCanvas()
mapTool = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(mc)
mapTool.setLayer(layer)
mc.setMapTool(mapTool)
mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(onFeatureIdentified)
```

I tried to insert it in my plugin:

Connecting the button:

```py
self.dlg.pbAddFeature.clicked.connect(self.addFeature)

def onFeatureIdentified(feature):
    fid = feature.id()
    print ("feature selected : " + str(fid))

def addFeature(self):
    layer = myLayer
    mc=iface.mapCanvas()
    mapTool = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(mc)
    mapTool.setLayer(layer)
    mc.setMapTool(mapTool)
    mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(self.onFeatureIdentified)
```

But nothing happens.

The only way I found to have an action was to extract the maptool as a property in my plugin.

```py
Class MyQGISPlugin
    mapTool = None
```

then connecting the `onFeatureIdentified` method in the run method:

```py
self.mapTool = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(self.iface.mapCanvas())
self.mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(self.onFeatureIdentified)
```

then defining the `onFeatureIdentified` method:

```py
def onFeatureIdentified(feature):
    print(type(feature))
```

and then defining the press Button method:

```py
def addFeature(self):
    self.mapTool.setLayer(self.myLayer)
    self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.mapTool)
```

When In click the pushButton on my dialog, the cursor changes and I can click in `myLayer` but it prints me `<class 'my_qgis_plugin.my_qgis_plugin.MyQGISPlugin'>` instead of a feature. And it prints `AttributeError: 'MyQGISPlugin' object has no attribute 'id'` when I use the first `onFeatureIdentified` to print the feature's id.

Comment: Try to change `def onFeatureIdentified(feature):` to `def onFeatureIdentified(self, feature):` If I'm not wrong your `onFeatureIdentified` is a method of your plugin: it expects `def myfunction(self, arg1, arg2, ...):`

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the problem. I was blinded by the QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature code implementation.

Comment: @aurel_nc Made an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your code by replacing `def onFeatureIdentified(feature):` with `def onFeatureIdentified(self, feature):`

If I'm not wrong your `onFeatureIdentified` is a method of your plugin: it expects something like `def myfunction(self, arg1, arg2, ...):`

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting implementation of QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature [here](https://github.com/neogeo-technologies/GeofoncierEditeurRFU/blob/master/edge_creator.py)